# How to add a label and edit controls inside an already existing groupbox in a design mode using delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

As one of my requirements, I have to add a label and edit field to an existing groupbox in delphi. But how many times, i add a label inside an existing groupbox it disappears or it wont get added. Is there an alternative way to do this?
Am not sure why but am able to add edit but not label

Comment: Its because label gets hidden away from the view behind other controls. you need to manually in your project drag the label to the groupbox of your choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess here. You are adding new components without first selecting the group box in the design surface. When you do that the component becomes a child of the form and disappears beneath other controls.

Here's how to do it:

- Click on the group box on the form design surface,
- then double click on the label in the palette.

Alternatively:

- Single click on the label in the palette,
- then single click on the group box on the form design surface.

If you do get the component parent/child relationships messed up, you can inspect them in the Object TreeView (open this from the View menu). If the relationships are wrong, drag the child controls around in the Object TreeView, and drop them into their desired parents.

Comment: Your both options worked, thanks, My mistake was not selecting groupbox and trying to add by double clicking label and dragging it into groupbox.

Comment: Or simply: Click control you want to add ie. Label (StdCtrls) -> Click group box -> Move control to where you want it. You'll see if the control is a child of the group box by shifting the group box Top/Left a bit and seeing if the control (ie. Label) moves as well.